# Pymongo, TypeError : expected a character buffer object

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to connect and to read data in a MongoDB database, to learn Python. I'm using Pymongo and I have this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "secondtest.py", line 107, in <module>
user_info = dbco.find({})
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

This is my database.ini :

```
[postgresql]
host=monhostname
database=monpass
port=15000
user=monuser
password=monpass

[mongodb]
hostname=127.0.0.1
database=Mydatabase
username=Myname
password=Myn@me!
collection=measure
port=27017
```

And my code using it :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# secondtest.py

import psycopg2
import sys
import pymongo
from urllib import quote_plus
from pymongo import MongoClient
from configparser import ConfigParser

# Connection information in database.ini
params = ''
mongollection = ''

# Variables to connect to a database, to use a cursor object and to fetch all results from a query
mongoClient = ''
pgsqlClient = ''
pgsqlCursor = ''
pgsqlRecords = ''
mongoRecords = ''
dbco = ''

# Retrieve connection information from ini file
def dbConfig(section, filename='database.ini'):
    # Create a parser
    parser = ConfigParser()

    # Read config file
    parser.read(filename)

    # Get section, depending on the database engine
    db = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params = parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            db[param[0]] = param[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('Section {0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))

    # Return data or directly as a string
    if section == 'postgresql':
        return db
    elif section == 'mongodb':
        host = ''
        username = ''
        passwd = ''
        port = ''
        dbmongo = ''
        connectstring = ''

        # Make a string to connect to MongoDB
        for key, value in db.iteritems():
            if key == 'hostname':
                host = value.encode("utf-8")
            elif key == 'username':
               username = value
            elif key == 'password':
               passwd = value
            elif key == 'database':
               dbmongo = value
            elif key == 'collection':
               mongollection = value
            elif key == 'port':
               port = value

        connectstring = "mongodb://" + username + ":" + quote_plus(passwd) + "@" + host + ":" + port
        print("Internal test = " + connectstring)
        return connectstring.encode('iso-8859-1')

# Connection to MongoDB
def connectToMongoDb():
    # The f-string is only available in Python >= 3.6
    params = dbConfig('mongodb')
    print("Parameters : " + params)
    mongoClient = MongoClient(params)

    try:
        # print("Connection to database")
        dbco = mongoClient.mongollection
        print("Here")
        print("Test dbco : " + dbco)
        print("Connected to MongoDB !")
        return dbco
    except:
        return "Error : can't connect to MongoDB !"

# Close MongoDB connection
def closeMongoDbConnection():
    # try:
    mongoClient.close()
    return 'Connection closed'
    # except:
        # return "Can't close the connection. See if you already had one or if you didn't mispell its name."

# Make a query in MongoDB
def mongoDbQuery():
    #mongocursor = mongoClient.mongollection.find()
    #for document in cursor:
        #print(document)
    mongoClient.database_names()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataconnect =  connectToMongoDb()
    print("Connection\n")
    #mongoDbQuery()
    #collec = mongoClient.measure
    user_info = dbco.find({})
    print(user_info)
    print(closeMongoDbConnection())
```

Could you help me with this problem ? I think quote_plus() or even dbco = mongoClient.mongollection is what makes this error occurs. But I'm not 100% sure and I don't see, even with the documentation, how could I resolve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it again and changed some little things. Now, it works. Here is the code, for people who'd need it in the future.

```
import sys
import pymongo
from urllib import quote_plus
from pymongo import MongoClient
from configparser import ConfigParser

client = MongoClient()
connected = ''

# Retrieve connection information from ini file
def dbConfig(section, filename='database.ini'):
    # Keep result in global variable when the function is finished
    global client

    # Create a parser
    parser = ConfigParser()

    # Read config file
    parser.read(filename)

    # Get section, depending on the database engine
    db = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params = parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            db[param[0]] = param[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('Section {0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))

    # Return data or directly as a string
    if section == 'postgresql':
        return db
    elif section == 'mongodb':
        # Variables for the connection
        host = ''
        username = ''
        passwd = ''
        port = ''
        connectstring = ''

        # Make a string to connect to MongoDB
        for key, value in db.iteritems():
            if key == 'hostname':
                host = value.encode("utf-8")
            elif key == 'username':
               username = value
            elif key == 'password':
               passwd = value
            elif key == 'database':
               dbmongo = value
            elif key == 'collection':
               mongollection = value
            elif key == 'port':
               port = value

        # Make the URI needed for the connection to Mongo DB
        passwing = "mongodb://" + username + ":" + quote_plus(passwd) + "@" + host + ":" + port
        client = MongoClient(passwing)
        return client

# Close MongoDB connection
def closeMongoDbConnection():
    # Try to close the connection to Mongo DB
    try:
        client.close()
        return 'Connection closed'
    except:
        return "Can't close the connection. See if you already had one or if you didn't mispell its name."

# Connection to MongoDB
def connectToMongoDb(mydb):
    db = client.get_database(mydb)
    return db.measure

# Make a query in MongoDB
def mongoDbQuery():
    docs = connected.find().count()
    #for document in docs:
        #print(document)
    print(docs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connected = connectToMongoDb('neocampus')
    #docs = connected.find()
    # print(test)
    #for document in docs:
        #print(document)
    mongoDbQuery()

    # Show if the connection to Mongo DB is a success or not
    print(closeMongoDbConnection())
```

The problems were : 
 - about global variables in and out of functions
 - the database variable empty (because of that)
 - a first call of MongoClient()

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading your code. I see in the beginning of the program, you create the `dbco` variable to point to an empty string:

```
dbco = ''
```

following after that, I see you define a couple functions, then you call `find()` on that string:

```
user_info = dbco.find({})
```

You're passing `{}` (empty dict) as parameter to the method... but as you can see in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), this method needs another string as first parameter. That causes the error you see.

Now I'm not entirely sure how to fix it because I don't know what you mean. Maybe you mean to use the `dataconnect` variable, since that is the one that gets the results of the `connectToMongoDb` function:

```
dataconnect =  connectToMongoDb()
```

Comment: Well, I used `db.measure.insert({"second":"un second test"})` to add something in MongoDB. Even with `user_info = dbco.find({"second"})`, I have the same error. And of course, using `dataconnect.find` instead of `dbco.find` is the same.